# CAML query range does not bring correct number of results

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, search, search-results, caml-query, caml

I have a CAML Query that brings 53 results. When I add the range below I get 13 results instead of 10.

```
<Range>
    <StartAt>41</StartAt>
    <Count>10</Count>
</Range>
```

- StartAt=1 and Count=10 brings 10 results
- StartAt=11 and Count=10 brings 10 results
- StartAt=21 and Count=10 brings 10 results
- StartAt=31 and Count=10 brings 10 results
- StartAt=41 and Count=10 **brings 13 results**

Any idea why I am getting 13 results instead of 5?

Here is the complete CAML Query:

```
<QueryPacket xmlns='urn:Microsoft.Search.Query'>
<Query>
    <Context>
        <QueryText language="en-US" >ContentType:CustomDoc</QueryText>
    </Context>
    <SupportedFormats Format="urn:Microsoft.Search.Response.Document.Document" />
    <ResultProvider>SharePointSearch</ResultProvider>
    <Range>
        <StartAt>41</StartAt>
        <Count>10</Count>
    </Range>
    <EnableStemming>true</EnableStemming>
    <EnableSpellCheck>Suggest</EnableSpellCheck>
    <IncludeSpecialTermsResults>true</IncludeSpecialTermsResults>
    <IncludeRelevantResults>true</IncludeRelevantResults>
    <ImplicitAndBehavior>true</ImplicitAndBehavior>
    <TrimDuplicates>false</TrimDuplicates>
    <Properties>
        <Property name="Rank" />        
        <Property name="Title" />       
        <Property name="Size" />        
        <Property name="Path" />        
        <Property name="Description" /> 
        <Property name="Write" />       
        <Property name="propertyNumber" />
        <Property name="propertyId" />
        <Property name="propertyTitle" />
        <Property name="propertyShortTitle" />
    </Properties>
    <SortByProperties>
        <SortByProperty name="propertyShortTitle" direction="Ascending" />
    </SortByProperties>
    <IncludeRefinementResults>
        <Refiners>              
            <Refiner>refiner1</Refiner>
            <Refiner>refiner2</Refiner>
            <Refiner>refiner3</Refiner>
            <Refiner>refiner4(filter=101)</Refiner>
            <Refiner>refiner5</Refiner>
            <Refiner>refiner6</Refiner>
        </Refiners>
        <MaxShallowRefinementHits>2000</MaxShallowRefinementHits>
    </IncludeRefinementResults>     
</Query>
```

UPDATE:

- StartAt=41 and Count=6 **brings 6 results**
- StartAt=41 and Count=7 **brings 13 results** ?????

Comment: We will need more to go on. Can you sanitize and share the XML for the whole list or library or whatever this is? Can you share the results for the above queries? Can you share your complete CAML query?

Comment: I have updated the question with the query. Thanks!

Comment: What if you dont specify count? how many results you get.

Comment: I get 13 results, starting at 41.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to try few things (one by one) to see if it works

1. Dont specify the count parameter. By default, it anyways gives 10 results
2. Set  `<TrimDuplicates>true</TrimDuplicates>`
3. set   `<IncludeSpecialTermsResults>false</IncludeSpecialTermsResults>`

Comment: can you share the results if possible?

Comment: Unfortunately I can not share the results. I do not think it it related to the results... I believe this is a SharePoint bug...